# Mock dutchcoders/goftp for unit testing

Tags: unit-testing, go, ftp, mocking

I'm using [dutchcoders/goftp](https://github.com/dutchcoders/goftp) in my code, and for unit testing purpose, I need to mock it.

Thing is this component doesn't have interface, nor avaible mocks, so I tried to create some:

in `goftp/ftp.go`,

I added interface:

```
type FTPIface interface {
    Close() error
    Walk(path string, walkFn WalkFunc) (err error)
    Rename(from string, to string) (err error)
    Login(username string, password string) (err error)
}
```

Now I can mock all the methods I use but `Connect()`, because connect has no receiver.

You use like like that:

```
if client, err = goftp.Connect(Host); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
```

So I tried to change it to be able to mock it:

```
func NewMyFTP(ftpIface goftp.FTPIface, host, user, password, name string) (*MyFTP, error) 
{ 
    if Client, err = ftpIface.Connect(Host); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    if err = Client.Login(user, password); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
}
```

and added `Connect()` to interface definition

```
Connect(addr string) (*FTP, error)
```

Thing is I can mock connect, but it will return a FTP object, and I will not be able to mock `Login()`

So, what should I do ?

1. Change go client ? I wouldn't like to do that, as I have implemented it in all my code.
2. Implement a dev ftp server: Can be a good and simple idea, but I will mix Unit test and functional test, keeping an external dependency.
3. Finding a technical solution to my problem and mock it ?

Comment: Rather than modifying the dependency source code you can declare the interface in your project and also implement a thin wrapper around the dependency, the wrapper would have no logic other then delegating to the dependency. This can also be used to solve your `Connect`-returning-`*FTP` problem.

Comment: Follow the robustness principle: declare an interface where you use it, and pass in a mock for unit tests, do *not* declare the interface in the dependency. In golang, you return a struct/actual type, and you accept interfaces for that very reason

Comment: @mkopriva can you give me a hint about how should I implement the wrapper ?

Comment: @JuliatzindelToro here's an example that may help clarify how to abstract 3rd party call-chains using interfaces and thin wrappers: https://play.golang.com/p/joTfxqamDiN

Comment: I'm checking it !

Comment: What does Logical refers to in your example ? I can't figure it out !

Comment: Just can't do it :( Will try tomorrow.